# Getting what the current class is declared as

Tags: javascript, oop

I am writing a class which manipulates some innerHTML & onclick tags of a div, which puts some function in it that is calls something within the class, however, as there are going to be more than one use of the class on a single page.

I was wondering if it was possible within the class to workout what that particular object had been labelled?

```
function Bob() {
    this.test = function()
    {
        alert('test');
    }
    this.Bob = function()
    {
        element.onClick = function() {(some piece of code).test();};
        element.innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + (some piece of code) + ".test();\">Test</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, the class above is not the class im using, its something to show whats going on (of sorts)

Comment: What class? There's no such thing as a class in javascript. Javascript doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Incognito don't be cantankerous, it may not be called a class, but its acts close enough to one for me to refer to it as one if i want. its not like its throwing anyone off

Comment: @ChrisGoddard the word your looking for is "object". You did not use any form of `[[Prototype]]` so your not allowed to use the term "class"

Comment: @Raynos fair enough, i did not know that, i think ill call it something that annoys me, lol. But will prototype do what im trying to persuade it to do (essentially get a string of what the object is declared as?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Bob() {}
Bob.prototype.test = function () { 
  /* do things */ 
};
Bob.prototype.Bob = function () {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.test();
  }.bind(this));
  toArray(element.childNodes).forEach(function (node) {
    element.removeChild(node);
  });
  var button = document.create("button");
  button.classList.add("button-style");
  element.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.test();
  }.bind(this));
};
```

You want to use `.bind` to bind functions to a `thisContext

Comment: it codes an image to do a function
also, for the moment i have just added a variable to the top and that is set after its declared to the name of the object, then its just called and evaled
eval("h.onclick = function() {" + this.selfObject + ".Hide(" + this.reloadOnClose + ")}");

Comment: Chill, that was to save time, i just stick with "javascript:;" then stick it in the onclick or attach it to some other function.

Comment: so i could use the string as an declare to an object. so it was either eval or setTimeout

Comment: @ChrisGoddard I stopped ranting and offered you a DOM alternative.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for being a crazy fool, but it was more of a random idea

Comment: +1 because I have no idea how you worked out what the OP wanted.

Comment: @RobG 

var Fish = new Bob();
var Finger = new Bob();
Fish.whatAmI();      //Will return Fish,
Finger.whatAmI();    //Will return Finger,

probably should have lead with that

Comment: @ChrisGoddard you can't do that without some epic hackery.

Comment: @Raynos Bugger. Ah well, your way is much neater, probably should have just gone for that.

Comment: @ChrisGoddard I forgot to warn you it's un-tested and not cross browser compliant (for example you have to implement `toArray` and `.eventListener` and `.classList` are not cross browser compliant)

Comment: @Raynos - and requires ES5 Function.prototype.bind. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function Bob() {
    var self = this;

    this.test = function()
    {
        alert('This is the Bob class');
    }

    element.onClick = function() {
       self.test();
    };
}
```

Due to how closures work the "self" variable will still be inscope within that element's onclick even after the Bob constructor returns.

Simply have different classes return different alert messages inside the test function

Comment: that worked for the onclick addition, but unfortunately not within innerHTML manipulation (wasn't expecting it to :()